# DB for credentials

Tags: database, cursor, android-sqlite

How can I create a sqlite db that only has one row to store a username and password value. anytime an attempt to add additional data is made, the application to not allow.

```
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " +
    DATABASE_NAME + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"

                + COLUMN_USER + " text not null,"
                + COLUMN_CODE + " text not null);";

    db.execSQL(sqlDataStore);
}
```

Comment: You should probably be storing credentials in the Keychain, not a sqlite database. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " +
TABLE_NAME + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"

            + COLUMN_USER + " text not null,"
            + COLUMN_CODE + " text not null);";
```

it's `TABLE_NAME` not `DATABASE_NAME`.

if you want any better answer, submit the code you wrote to add new data.